# Matching PyTorch w/ CNTK (VGG on CIFAR)

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, cntk, pytorch, mxnet

I am trying to understand how PyTorch works and want to replicate a simple CNN training on CIFAR. The [CNTK](https://github.com/ilkarman/Blog/blob/master/DL-Examples/CNTK_CIFAR.ipynb) script gets to **0.76** accuracy after 168 seconds of training (10 epochs), which is similar to my [MXNet](https://github.com/ilkarman/Blog/blob/master/DL-Examples/MXNet_CIFAR.ipynb) script (**0.75** accuracy after 153 seconds).

However, my [PyTorch](https://github.com/ilkarman/Blog/blob/master/DL-Examples/PyTorch_CIFAR.ipynb) script is lagging behind a lot at **0.71** accuracy and 354 seconds. I appreciate I will get differences in accuracy due to stochastic weight initialisation, etc. However the difference across frameworks is much greater than difference within a framework, initialising randomly between runs.

The reasons I can think of:

- MXNet and CNTK are initialized to xavier/glorot uniform; not sure how to do this in PyTorch and so perhaps the weights are initialised to 0
- CNTK does gradient-clipping by default; not sure if PyTorch has the equivalent
- Perhaps the bias is dropped in PyTorch by default
- I use SGD with momentum; perhaps the PyTorch implementation of momentum is a bit different

Edit:

I have tried specifying the weight initialisation, however it seems to have no big effect:

```
self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 50, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
init.xavier_uniform(self.conv1.weight, gain=np.sqrt(2.0))
init.constant(self.conv1.bias, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I try to answer your first two questions:

- weight initialization: different kinds of layers have their own method, you can find the default weight initialization of all these layers in the following link: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/tree/master/torch/nn/modules
- gradient-clipping: you might want to use `torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm`

In addition, I am curious why you don't use `torchvision.transforms` `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` and `torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10` to load and preprocess your data?

There is a similar image classification tutorial of cifar for Pytorch 
http://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-beginner-blitz-cifar10-tutorial-py
Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have tried playing around with weight initialisation and gradient-clipping - however still can't get the same accuracy and training-time as CNTK. In-fact when I compare it to [Chainer](https://github.com/ilkarman/Blog/blob/master/DL-Examples/Chainer_CIFAR.ipynb) the accuracy is lower by 7 ppt and it is 2 minutes slower. I don't use the default data-set and data-loader because I am creating this example across all 9 different DL frameworks and my goal is to get a series of scripts that are very similar and easy to compare (same data) - so I take the data as given/exogenous.